# MinGW: building a dynamic library with opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, mingw

A want to build a simple dll, that shows an image:

```
#include <opencv2\core\core.hpp>
#include<opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;

void showimagedata(uchar * dataBuffer,int width,int height)
{
    Mat image(Size(width, height), CV_8UC1, dataBuffer, Mat::AUTO_STEP);
    imshow("image",image);
}
```

How can I compile it with MinGW?

I tried the following:

```
g++ -c -fPIC showimg.cpp -o showimg.o -I"C:\opencv\build-mingw\install\include" -L"C:\opencv\build-mingw\install\x86\mingw\lib" -lopencv_core247 -lopencv_highgui247
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,libshowimg.so.1 -o libshowimg.so.1.0.1  showimg.o
```

but it seems that the linker cant find the symbols.

Filenames and paths are correct, but I'm not certain about the naming conventions.
The two libs are called: libopencv_core247.dll.a libopencv_highgui247.dll.a

Comment: besides your current problem, - it won't show anything, unless you add a `waitKey();` at the end

Comment: your 1st line compiles only, so the linker stuff should go into the 2nd